# Why is my response.get blocked in express/node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, blocked

I have the following code :-

```
var express = require('express');
var events = require('events');

var app = express();
var kick = new events.EventEmitter();

app.get('/info', function(req, res) {
    console.log('at A');
    kick.once('kick', function() {
        console.log('at C');
        res.send('info');
    });
    console.log('at B');
});

app.get('/info2', function(req, res) {
    res.send('info2');
});

app.get('/kick', function(req, res) {
    kick.emit('kick');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

if I enter localhost:8080/info into my browser, I get the expected output which is :-

```
at A
at B
```

if I then emit the kick event I get the expected output :-

```
at A
at B
at C
```

However if I request the info twice, the 2nd call doesn't get processed until the first one is complete with the kick event. Why is that? Where is the block happening?

I request info2 ok while the first get is waiting for the kick.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the 2nd call doesn't get processed"_? Because the second call is also logging `at A, at B` and waits for the `kick` event.

Comment: the 2nd call does not get to the 'at A' stage at all until the first call is completed. i don't think i have blocked the event loop since i can make info2 calls ok.

Comment: For me the second call is showing the same as the first call, which is to be expected. So I'm wondering how you're testing, and if the code you're showing is the exact code that you're testing with.

Comment: i am testing with three separate instances of firefox. typed in localhost:8080/info twice. i can see one set of 'at A, at B' and then after i kick, i can see the 2nd set.

Comment: Try using something like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), browsers tend to have heuristics regarding connections to the same host that might be getting in your way (for instance, if one connection is pending, FF may not open a new one).

Comment: thanks dude, it was firefox

Answer (score 0):

When a request comes into play it expects to eventually receive a `res.send` to finish the connection. So in your case if you got to `/info` it defines a callback for an event that never happens and so `res.send` isn't called and the request stays *blocked* (more like pending not blocked) waiting for `res.send` which in your code only happens after a request **and** a `trigger('kick')`.

Comment: pending?....so what is node doing while it's pending? if i make a info2 request while info is 'pending' that works fine. but no new info requests can be made.